# What is the best way to clean a brick paver patio?

Tags: cleaning, pavers

Looking for ideas on how to best clean a brick paver patio.

Background:
I had a brick paver patio installed three years ago.  The following year I had it sealed (not sure what product was used) with two coats of sealer.

The patio surely needs a good cleaning.  I have lots of trees and foliage falls and stains the patio.  There are a few places where weeds are starting go grow between pavers.  There is decent drainage but a few areas have dirt accumulated on top of the pavers.

I'm thinking of having my vinyl siding power washed and was wondering if the pavers could also get power washed.  I worry the power washing will dig out the sand between the bricks.  Power washing paver patio a good idea?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the pressure washer will dig out the sand between the bricks.  I would not recommend it.

I would suggest a stiff brush with dish detergent mixed with water.  If that is not strong enough try some professional paver cleaning products from your local home improvement store.

Comment: I can confirm your pressure washer remark. I used pressure on my clay paver patio and the weeds got _worse_, *_much worse_*.